# Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded when try to open phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in E:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\select_lang.lib.php on line 458

i changed max_execution_time = 6000 in php.ini file. After changing also same error.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error and this is what i found helpful, just in case someone stumbles upon this. Please go to

```
xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\config.default.php
```

Look for : $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = 600;

You can change '600' to any higher value, like '6000'.

Maximum execution time in seconds is (0 for no limit).

This will fix your error.

credits to @user1900623 and simon-east

Answer (score 2):

You can change the `max_execution_time` in your php.ini. The path should be E:\xampp\php\phpVERSION\php.ini if i'm correct.

Comment: Have you reboot Apache ?

Comment: It still says `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds` ? You probably edited the wrong php.ini then.

Comment: i made change in the following path : E:\xamp\php\php.ini

Comment: And what does it says now ? The same amount of seconds ?

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy way to solve this problem.

Steps:

1. Open **XAMPP** Control Panel.
2. Click on **CONFIG** tab of **APACHE** Service.
3. Select PHP (**php.ini**) from the DropDown.
   Now a file will open in your default Text Editor.
4. Search for the keyword **MAX_EXECUTION_TIME**.
5. By default it is set to : 30 , make it a **higher** value. (160 Worked for me).
6. **Save** the file (CTRL+S).
7. **Stop** All service in XAMPP Control Panel.
8. **Quit** XAMPP.
9. **Restart** XAMPP.
10. **Restart ALL Services** (i.e. APACHE)

Refresh your WordPress Dashboard.

You are done.